# Printable to File

Tags: java, printing

I have a printable object which I want to automatically print to a file.

I can print it to a file through the print dialog but I have to print 135 different generated documents and would rather do it procedurally instead of manually.

The format doesn't particularly matter, just so long as I can convert it to a pdf.

Comment: To output the printable to a file instead of submitting it as a print job.

Comment: @Did you mean java.awt.print.Printable?

Comment: @Jayan yep, sorry should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've worked it out. I stumbled upon this page on the java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing2d.fm1.html#998764

The part of interest is "Streaming 2D Graphics".

I ended up with this:

```
public static boolean printToPostScript(File file, Printable printable) {
    try {
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        String mime = "application/postscript";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        StreamPrintService printer;
        StreamPrintServiceFactory[] factories =
            PrinterJob.lookupStreamPrintServices(mime);

        if(factories.length > 0) {
                printer = factories[0].getPrintService(out);
                job.setPrintService(printer);
                job.setPrintable(printable);
                job.print();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No suitable print services");
            return false;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This can be modified to print directly to PDF but you will need a PDF printer available. So I am just printing to postscript and using `ps2pdf` to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attributes.add(new Destination(new java.net.URI("file:C:/myfile1.pdf")));      
try  
{
    job.print(attributes);    // Print the job if the user didn't cancel printing.
} 
catch(Exception e)
{    
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to remove the need to press "Okay", I didn't want to press okay 135 times.